# Why am I getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running into an issue with has not occurred to me until now. The error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`,  is appearing randomly so currently having a hard time debugging it.

Basically, I have a sort function that filters through JSON array. I use this function to order a mapping of components.

Function I use to sort data for mapping.

```
    function sortAll(data, orderDirection, valueToOrderBy) {
  
        // Filter the nulls in an array and the rest in another
        let nulls = data.filter((item) => item[valueToOrderBy] == null)
        let toSort = data.filter((item) => item[valueToOrderBy])
        
        // Sort the non-null values
        let sorted = toSort.sort((a, b) => {
          
          // Check if both values are numeric
          let aa = isNumeric(a[valueToOrderBy])
          let bb = isNumeric(b[valueToOrderBy])
          
          // If numerics
          if (aa.isNum && bb.isNum) {
            return aa.value - bb.value
          }
          
          // If strings
          return (a[valueToOrderBy]).toLowerCase() > (b[valueToOrderBy]).toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
        });
      
        // The sorting direction
        if (orderDirection === "desc") {
          sorted.reverse();
        }
        
        //  Add the nulls at the end of the returned array
        return sorted.concat(nulls);
      }
```

Here is my return function with the `sortAll` in use to map how a list:

```
        <>
          <Container style={{ padding:"10px", justifyContent: "center" }}  maxWidth="lg">
            <Grid container className='tableGridContainer' alignItems="center" justify="center" direction="row" spacing={3}>
                    <Grid items xs={12} s={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                <List dense='true'>
                    {financialData && sortAll(financialData[2], 'desc', 'beta').slice(0,3)
                        .map((stock, index) => (
                            <ListItem>
                            <ListItemAvatar>
                            <Avatar>
                                {index + 1}
                            </Avatar>
                            </ListItemAvatar>
                            <ListItemText
                            primary={stock.symbol}
                            secondary={financialData && financialData[5].filter((i) => i.symbol === stock.symbol).map(
                                filteredSymbol => (
                                    <>
                                        {filteredSymbol.company}
                                    </>
                                ))}
                            />
                            </ListItem>
                        ))
                            }
                </List>
                </Grid>
         </>
```

Please note that there is data flowing to this component. Here is a deeper look into my error:

```
  75 |   function sortAll(data, orderDirection, valueToOrderBy) {
  76 | 
  77 |       // Filter the nulls in an array and the rest in another
> 78 |       let nulls = data.filter((item) => item[valueToOrderBy] == null)
     | ^  79 |       let toSort = data.filter((item) => item[valueToOrderBy])
  80 |       
  81 |       // Sort the non-null values
```

That is where the issue arises, not sure why though... Any tips or leads anyone else has to know why this is happening?

Comment: so data is undefined

Comment: I'm guessing `financialData[2]` is underfined. You've smartly added a check for `financialData`, but you should also check `financialData[2]` before using it